# Adding nodes with namespaces to an XML file with Nokogiri

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri

I'm having trouble editing an XML file. I'm currently trying to use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/), but I'm open to any other Ruby library to solve this problem.

I'm trying to add a Node set inside another node set. Both have some interesting namespacing. Here's the code. I'm trying to add the new_node to the parent right after the first `<p:sp>`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

parent = <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="mv" mc:PreserveAttributes="mv:*">
  <p:spTree>
    <p:sp>
      <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1" name="Title 1"/>
      </p:nvSpPr>
    </p:sp>
  </p:spTree>
</p:sld>
EOF

new_node = <<EOF 
<p:sp>
  <p:cNvPr id="2" name="Title 2"/>
  <a:off x="1524000" y="4572000"/>
</p:sp>
EOF

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(parent)
@doc.xpath('.//p:sp').after(new_node)
```

@doc looks something like the XML below after the above code runs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="mv" mc:PreserveAttributes="mv:*">
  <p:spTree>
    <p:sp>
      <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1" name="Title 1"/>
      </p:nvSpPr>
    </p:sp>

   <p:p:sp>
    <p:p:cNvPr name="Title 2" id="2"/>
    <p:a:off x="1524000" y="4572000"/>
   </p:p:sp>

  </p:spTree>
</p:sld>
```

Notice it namespaced everything under p: again. The two nodes should be `<p:sp>` and `<a:off>` not `<p:p:sp>` and `<p:a:off>` I could just remove the p: from the new_node but the a:off would still be namespaced under p: which it can't be. I know I must be doing some wrong. The end result I'm looking for is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="mv" mc:PreserveAttributes="mv:*">
  <p:spTree>
    <p:sp>
      <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1" name="Title 1"/>
      </p:nvSpPr>
    </p:sp>
    <p:sp>
      <p:cNvPr name="Title 2" id="2"/>
      <a:off x="1524000" y="4572000"/>
    </p:sp>
  </p:spTree>
</p:sld>
```

Comment: From the Nokogiri homepage: "XML is like violence - if it doesn’t solve your problems, you are not using enough of it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looks like Nokogiri was the problem. Hpricot to the rescue! (RIP _why)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby    
require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'

parent = <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="mv" mc:PreserveAttributes="mv:*">
  <p:spTree>
    <p:sp>
      <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1" name="Title 1"/>
      </p:nvSpPr>
    </p:sp>
  </p:spTree>
</p:sld>
EOF

new_node = <<EOF 
  <p:sp>
    <p:cNvPr id="2" name="Title 2"/>
    <a:off x="1524000" y="4572000"/>
  </p:sp>
EOF


doc = Hpricot(parent)

doc.search('//p:sp').after(new_node)
```

And the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld mc:PreserveAttributes="mv:*" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" mc:Ignorable="mv" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
  <p:sptree>
    <p:sp>
      <p:nvsppr>
        <p:cnvpr name="Title 1" id="1" />
      </p:nvsppr>
    </p:sp>

    <p:sp>
     <p:cnvpr name="Title 2" id="2" />
     <a:off x="1524000" y="4572000" />
    </p:sp>

  </p:sptree>
</p:sld>
```